# Counting Specific text on a page

Tags: jquery

I have an html document that has a 'status' column. I need to count how many of these are marked Available or not Available.

I've tried to do something like this

```
$("td:contains(Available)" ).length;
```

but this is also picking up the "Not Available"'s. Is there a way to only select the Available's?

A example of the web page
http://www.cats-can.org/animals/list?Species=Cat

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$("td:contains(Available)" ).length - $("td:contains(Not Available)" ).length;
```

If the only text in the column is "Available", you could do:

```
$("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "Available";
}).length;
```

Comment: don't know why I didn't think of that. Thank you!